# silverlight event on server or client

Tags: silverlight, events

I have read that silverlight application will be downloaded as a XAP file on the browser and then the plug-in on the client machine will take care of executing it( pls correct me if I am wrong). If this is the case, suppose lets say my application has a button, and I have a click event on it. Now, If I clicks that button, will the event executes on client machine(Browser) or on the server??

Please let me know.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code written for a silverlight project is compiled to an assembly which is packaged in the XAP.  All the code will run on the client.  In order to get things to run on the server you will need use some from of service mechanism such as WCF.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in a Silverlight application executes on the client. If you need actions taken on the server, you will need to communicate with it using something else, like WCF services.